# How to pass value from view to controller without using anchor tag and forms in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Used session in my page but expected output not coming for me.i am using ZendSkeletonApplication and ZfcUser

in view/done.phtml

$sessionContainer = new \Zend\Session\Container('myNameSpace');

$checking="Got it";

$sessionContainer->myVar = $checking;

In Controller/UserController.php

public function doneAction()

```
{
    $result=$this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $sessionContainer = new \Zend\Session\Container('myNameSpace');
    $confirmation=$sessionContainer->myVar;
    print_r($confirmation); 
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to pass value to the controller in the current request?

Comment: yes..when loading done.phtml that value want to pass from view to controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot send information to the Controller from your view script, since the view(s) are rendered after all the controller->actions are called.

Advice from me would be to not do any logic in your view scripts especially if it would alter the execution of the controller. This would mean that you can place this logic in the controller itself.

The example with the session will not work, because as explained above, the view script executes after the controller, therefore if you set something in the session from the view script, the controller wouldn't "know" about it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.I placed the logic code in controller itself.Thanks